# creating a new project In visual studio code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

[image]So I am trying to create a new project in visual studio code. I was able to create one successfully a few weeks ago but now when I am creating, it shows me an error. Can you please help me why is it giving me an error? I searched alot but could not find anything. Below is the error :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why error occurs. But I recommend you to clean npm cache.

```
npm cache clean -f
```